# log filtering in xcode possible?

Tags: xcode, swift, logging

in android we can create log entries as follow:

```
Log.v("TAG","MESSAGE");
```

and then we can filter for the TAG in the catlog.

Is there any similar way to filter the log in XCODE ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not available by default but there are third-party solutions like XCGLogger that allows this — https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I guess this is more for detailed logging. This framework will not help in filtering the log in a tool, right?

Comment: Xcode console does not have log filtering tools. Framework may help with granular configuration of log levels as well as per class control of logging.

Comment: Actually you can save your logs and analyze them with Console.app it is able to open and filter any free form log file. Not really convenient as will require re-save logs to disk, but should work.